# my question is about how can i add my new css_style file to the theme in opencart?

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, opencart-3

For example, on my home page I'd like to have a different stylesheet to the default one, or one that will over ride the default styles with my custom sheet.

I tried so many solutions but there is no result can anyone put me into the right direction.

Comment: Hey Omar, why don't you share the theme you're using and at least list what you've done so far. This will help us to try and determine what hasn't worked and, hopefully, suggest something that may work

Comment: im using opencart v3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding CSS stylesheet to pages based on route in OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285961/adding-css-stylesheet-to-pages-based-on-route-in-opencart)

Comment: im using the default opencart theme

Comment: Omar, @MohitGupta has suggested a good answer, have a look at that and you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there are several ways you can add a stylesheet in OpenCart themes

### the simple way

in file `catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/template/common/header.twig add the link to your stylesheet in`< head >` right after your last css file.

> remember that your custom stylesheet has to go after your default stylesheet for the styles to override them.

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/stylesheet/CUSTOM_STYLESHEET.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

### the more sophisticated way

OpenCart allows you to set the stylesheet from the contorller. this is often used by modules to add their styles to the head tag and also allow site optimization modules to compress the stylesheet file.

you can test it by editing a controller file for homepage (as an example)

in file `catalog/controller/common/home.php` on `line 7` add this code

```php
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME/stylesheet/CUSTOM_STYLESHEET.css');
```

I hope this helps

Comment: An even simpler way is just to modify the default stylesheet.css

Comment: Yeah! There is even a simple way - add the styles in the theme files with <style> tag.

Comment: Except that wouldn't be valid because <style> tags can only be in the <head> and wouldn't be simpler because they'd be all over the place. There is nothing wrong with editing the default stylesheet because it cannot be modified by vQmod or OCMOD and there is no reason to keep the original.

Comment: You do you think <style> tags can be only in the <head>? you can place them all over the place. that is how people used to develop and a lot still use that in modules. but really it is not good practice since you are spreading around the styles when you should keep everything in one place. editing the default stylesheet is also not a good option since you are preventing future update so we try never to edit any core files even in themes.

Comment: Yes it works wherever you put it but it is invalid HTML anywhere except the <head> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303416/does-style-have-to-be-in-the-head-of-an-html-document

Comment: Yes, I see, you are right. Always thought of it as bad practice for a reason) well, frankly, the only way we are adding custom styles is via the module controller. everything else just seems too dirty.

Comment: This only adds the CSS to the homepage. I tried adding the same script to header.php and it didn't show up in the html for any page. How do you add a CSS file sitewide?

Comment: you can add this script to your catalog/controller/common/header.php  file. this will be shared among all pages.